# How to change a useState before history.push in react router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to change a state in the parent container onClick that will have to make changes on the next router being routed by `history.push`. But when I change the state on click along with routing, routing takes place and changes doesn't show till the new render again. How can I solve this? I will paste some code

```
<OptionButton
  style={{ marginTop: 22 }}
  onClick={() => {
    setAnimationClass('none');
    history.push('information');
  }}
>
```

I need setAnimationClass to take place before the history.push

Comment: Did you catch the changes with `componentDidUpdate` lifecycle or `useEffect` hook in the component which you want to render smt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you only set it to `'none'` when navigating to `'information'`? Perhaps you could could make use of useEffect() to do the trick. If you change the animationClass anywhere else it might be wiser to make another state property and modify it in your `onClick` and listen for these changes in `useEffect`

```
useEffect(() => {
  if (animationClass === 'none') {
    history.push('information');
  }
}, [animationClass]);
```

Answer (score 1):

From React documantation:

> setState() does not immediately mutate this.state but creates a pending state transition. Accessing this.state after calling this method can potentially return the existing value.
>
> There is no guarantee of synchronous operation of calls to setState and calls may be batched for performance gains.

If you want something to happen with absolute guarantee only after setState, [react docs offer a solution](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) - use either setState callback or componentDidUpdate method.

If you are using hooks, then useEffect can be used. Example:

```
const [animationClass, setAnimationClass] = useState()

const onClick = () => {
  setAnimationClass('none')
}

useEffect(() => {
   if(animationClass ==='none') history.push('information')
}, [animationClass])
```

Comment: Pressing the back button after this render will cause bugs though

Comment: If you keep useState and useEffect within the same component and animationClass initial state is not 'none', I believe its fine. useEffect triggers only on animationClass change. If something else changes animationClass, then indeed you can run into a bug.

Sadly. I don't believe hooks provide as perfect solution as classes setState callback.

Comment: You would then need another state  "didOnClickDoThis" :/